# Refactoring single threaded GUI code for multithreaded scenarious

Tags: c++, multithreading, user-interface, marshalling

The usual scenario, there is an MFC/Win32/WTL/wxWidgets/Qt application that does something useful. It was designed to be single threaded, and there is some logic that handles errors/questions within processing blocks.

So, somewhere deep inside some class, a dialog can be fired that asks the user "Are you sure you want to complete the action?"/"Error with document layout" or something like that.

The problem is the dialog is fired from computationally heavy/strightforward code. Like FFT/image sharpening/file system de-fragmentation function, or something along the lines. Which could be launched in a worker thread easily, if not for the GUI. And would suit there better, as it would avoid GUI stalls that are so annoying for the user.

However, GUI cannot work in a worker thread, and dependency injection is pretty much impossible to do, because it would go down several layers of computational code. In a very unclean way from class interface standpoint, like `someclass instance(data_in, data_out, param1, param2, GUI_class_ref) : m_GUI(GUI_class_ref), ...` 3 or more levels deep.

Is there a pattern/checklist for such scenarios that can be used to marshall GUI prompts back to main thread and return the result back into the core of the computational code, if the code is split in multiple threads?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create synchronization context. It is a queue of commands to be executed by main thread. Worker thread adds command into this queue (which must be locked for single-thread access) and waits. Main thread processes this queue periodically, executes commands (for example, "Cancel operation" dialogs) and notifies worker threads about results.
In C#, this was done with delegates and arguments to call them. In C++, you can go with enum-coded messages to be processed in a switch (like messages in Windows programs.) Or create something with pointers to member functions + object pointer to call them from + arguments to call with.

Answer (score 2):

You are at one classical old code refactoring crossroad. Proper isolation and dependency injection is infeasible, so you are left with making the GUI context globally accessible. That is creating a Singleton. It doesn't necessarily need to be the GUI context directly, so at least some isolation is achieved. It can be some kind of manager which has the GUI context and accepts just specific one purpose calls from the computation code. You could make the GUI thread class a friend of this manager and make the GUI callbacks (upon closing the dialog) private.

I could give more specific ideas what to write as i went through exactly the same challenge (threadization of existing heavy app). But i am confused whether you want only the GUI thread to be running freely, or the background computation as well. The example dialog prompt you gave is confusing as it suggests a decision which needs to be answered to know whether continue at all (which would mean that computation is on hold).